# C# Form is unresponsive when scanning for files

Tags: c#, forms, lag

I made a program that scans trough a user selected folder, it will search for MP3 files and WAV files then it will calculate the total size of these files but when its doing all this the program is unresponsive labels will not update or just half and the window can't be dragged.

How do I fix this problem??

Link to download my program : [LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79630561/Media%20File%20Tester%20%28By%20MC-Softworks%29.rar)
Link to virus total : [LINK](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/84a10044ee00525f528ad11da617eae5237fd89fe513b925f1837870628c7b03/analysis/1372869840/)

EDIT :

Here is the code that checks the file size's :

```
    public string testFileSize(String dir)
    {
        if (MFILE_OPTION_SUBFOLDER_CHECKBOX.Checked == true)
        {
            double totalFileSize = 0;

            if (MFILE_OPTION_MP3_CHECKBOX.Checked == true)
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (string fileName in files)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

                    double fileSize = fi.Length;
                    totalFileSize += fileSize;
                }
            }

            if (MFILE_OPTION_WAV_CHECKBOX.Checked == true)
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (string fileName in files)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

                    double fileSize = fi.Length;
                    totalFileSize += fileSize;
                }
            }

            totalFileSize = Math.Round((totalFileSize / 1024f) / 1024f, 2);
            return totalFileSize.ToString() + " MB";
        }
        else
        {
            double totalFileSize = 0;

            if (MFILE_OPTION_MP3_CHECKBOX.Checked == true)
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.mp3", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                foreach (string fileName in files)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

                    double fileSize = fi.Length;
                    totalFileSize += fileSize;
                }
            }

            if (MFILE_OPTION_WAV_CHECKBOX.Checked == true)
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.wav", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                foreach (string fileName in files)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

                    double fileSize = fi.Length;
                    totalFileSize += fileSize;
                }
            }

            totalFileSize = Math.Round((totalFileSize / 1024f) / 1024f, 2);
            return totalFileSize.ToString() + " MB";
        }
    }
```

This is what I tried but them with all the file types as shown above ^^

```
                if (MFILE_OPTION_WAV_CHECKBOX.Checked == true)
            {
                BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
                {
                    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.wav", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                    foreach (string fileName in files)
                    {
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

                        double fileSize = fi.Length;
                        totalFileSize += fileSize;
                    }
                };

                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
```

But this returns 0 MB how?

Comment: time and again the UI thread lock problem. Run the scanning in a separate thread, use Task or BackgroundWorker

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but following a link that sends me an executable is not something I'm typically willing to do.  Not saying that anything malicious is attached, but generally i would rather see code than an executable.  Just FYI for the OP.

Comment: @Evan lewis Oh sorry I addded the code :)

Comment: @Nobleleader13245 You should not be linking to the code at all.  You should be *showing* the code.  If you have so much code that that's a problem, you need to create a short but complete example that demonstrates the problem that you *can* post in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `BackgroundWorker`for this. If you would supply some code we could help you better. So far I can only give you this:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s,e) =>
   {
      // Do your work
   };

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Example based on your code:

```
if (MFILE_OPTION_WAV_CHECKBOX.Checked == true)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.wav", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                foreach (string fileName in files)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

                    double fileSize = fi.Length;
                    totalFileSize += fileSize;
                }
            };

            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,e) =>
            {
                    //Update GUI
             }

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Ok now I used the backgroundworker but I can't return anything :S

Comment: @Nobleleader13245 You shouldn't need to return anything; it's asynchronous.  Use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to do stuff when the worker finishes; use the `Result` property to pass information between the two handlers.

Comment: Sorry I may ask something very stupid but how do I use RunWorkerCompleted and the Result property?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `BackgroundWorker` or something similar.

Your form is unresponsive because your doing the main job in the same thread as the user interface, that's why it's not responding.

If you want to update your user interface during the process of searching for files, you'll also need to use `Invokes` to change values